# We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, javascript, ethereumjs

[image]

I cannot add a candidate as it shows there is an error in the contract, but the code does not show any error.

```
**// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Election{

    address public manager;

    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string CfirstName;
        string ClastName;
        string CidNumber;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    mapping (address => bool) public voters;

    mapping (uint => Candidate) public candidates;

    uint public candidatesCount;

    event votedEvent (
        uint indexed_candidateId
    );


    constructor () public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function addCandidate (string memory _CfirstName, string memory _ClastName, string memory _CidNumber) public restricted{
        candidatesCount++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _CfirstName, _ClastName, _CidNumber, 0);
    }

    modifier restricted () {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }


    function vote (uint _candidateId) public {
        
        require(!voters[msg.sender]);

        require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidatesCount);

        voters[msg.sender] = true;

        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount ++;

        uint candidateId = _candidateId;

        emit votedEvent(_candidateId);
    }

    //users
    //register
    struct User {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string idNumber;
        string email;
        string password;
        address add;
    }

    mapping (uint => User) public users;

    uint public usersCount;

    function addUser (string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName, string memory _idNumber, string memory _email, string memory _password) public{
        usersCount++;
        users[usersCount] = User(_firstName, _lastName, _idNumber, _email, _password, msg.sender);
    }




}**
```

it also shows this in the data section of MetaMask.

**FUNCTION TYPE: Add Candidate (String, String, String)
Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 1337**

please help me solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran it in remix on mumbai and I was able to successfully add a candidate.

That error is pretty much saying that it is unable to estimate the amount of gas it will take for the function to succeed because it will fail.

Most likely, the issue is the way your calling it from the front end.

**Take this into consideration:**

Make sure the account you using to execute the function is same account that you deployed the contract with as you have a `restricted` modifier and you initialized the manager within the constructor.

Also, make sure calling the function with the proper types, as your entering a number value a string parameter, so keep that in mind as well.

If that doesn't work, make sure your instance of ganache is up, running, and configured properly

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147972/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-jaf-we-were-not-able-to-estimate-gas-there-might-b); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to check your contract!

1. try to add a candidate using etherscan. if you facing still this issue then. try to deploy another testnet.
2. try to estimate the gas from this function

As far as I know - you can't actually estimate the gas from solidity.

Two Related pieces of functionality that might be helpful:

You can potentially use

```
gasLeft(); Global Vars
```

You can call this function to understand how much gas is left in the transaction execution. You can also call this before and after a function call to understand how much gas that function used.

```
tx.gasprice is also available as a global variable
```

try to use raw Transaction in this function!